# Array validation fails with Laravel API (but I am sending an array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, api, request

I have an API built with Laravel. It does the following validation:

```
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'product_ids' => 'required|array',
            'product_ids*' => 'required|exists:products,id',
            'product_quantities' => 'required|array',
            'product_quantities*' => 'numeric',
        ], [
            'order_type.in' => trans('validation.order_type'),
        ]);
```

I am sending the following data in the request:
[image]

As text:

```
product_ids:[697,339]
product_quantities:[3,1]
```

However, I get as a response, 422:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "product_ids": [
      "The product_ids must be an array."
    ],
    "product_quantities": [
      "The product_quantities must be an array.",
      "The product_quantities must be a number."
    ]
  }
}
```

The same results appear using postman, thunder client and uno (dart). However, it works if I use axios (JS) with the same apparent data.

Any clue why the data I send is not always recognized as an array?

Comment: Just for sanity sake, `dd($reques->all());`, let's see what's coming in from the request

Comment: how to do you send data? what is the content type of your request?

Comment: You seems to send a string with `[` `]`

Comment: your obvious mistake is in validation rule . you defined `product_ids*` but it must be  `product_ids.*` and same about `product_quantities` .

Comment: @zohrehda this explains the "The product_quantities must be a number." error. But not the array validation, right? I am sending the data using uno (dart) post request. It seems to transform the data to a string and then encode it to a list of ints using utf8.

Comment: @zohrehda The content-type of my request is multipart/form-data. It is automatically defined by uno package. This is how I send the data in dart:  https://i.imgur.com/gW6XOD0.png

Comment: get a `dd($request->all())` to see how data is coming and share it please

Answer (score 1):

The request should be passed as an object when you pass data as an array.

**In Postman/AJAX/JS**

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'

JSON.stringify(); # for async  request
```

Example

```
sendProductIds(productIds) {
    body: JSON.stringify({ product_ids: productIds })
}

sendProductIds([1, 2, 3]);
```

---

And Validation should be

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'product_ids' => 'required|array',
    'product_ids.*' => 'integer|exists:products,id',
]);
```

Comment: (without changing the validation, since I believe the issue is only related to the second error)

I get the same response https://i.imgur.com/ATwAZKu.png

Comment: Content-type should be in headers. You must change this `'product_ids.*' => 'integer|exists:products,id',`

Answer (score 0):

There is difference in validation of a array parameter and elements in the array parameter:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all()[ 
  'product_ids' => 'required|array',
  'product_ids.*' => 
  'required|exists:products,id', 
  'product_quantities' => 'required|array',
  'product_quantities.*' => 'numeric', ],
['order_type.in' => trans('validation.order_type'), ]);
```

You need to put a `.` between the array parameter and `*`. That reffers elements in the array.